# Getting error on starting Solr from command prompt

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am newbie and in the learning path of Apache Solr .I am unable to start the Solr instance after hard deleting due to space issues . I get this error below if i try to start .
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.I am trying in Windows 10.

Comment: How did you delete what you had? Did you clean out the directory where the index files are stored? The log should show a more extensive error message - start Solr with the `-f` parameter. How are you starting Solr now?

Comment: Thanks , the Server shows up as Started .....but when accessing port 8983 of local host , I am getting below error :javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:162)

Comment: I deleted the Windows Folders by selecting them and pressing delete button to remove them from drive as some where showing up as corrupted ......My mistake ..

Comment: How to delete an Solr space smoothly and how to reinstall the Solr instance ....if one needs so ...

Comment: If you give the `-f` parameter when starting the server, you'll get the log directly in your cmd window - it'll show you the _actual error log_ from the server instead of just the web interface error. If you deleted the unpacked solr-x.x.x folder, and re-extracted it, you should be good to go. Make sure that there isn't any old instances of Solr still running when doing this (.. which shouldn't let you delete the folders anyway, but to make sure)